# How to print `1234567890` to `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0` with `C`?

Tags: c

> I am sorry, I do not want to work with `string` or `char*`.

---

Many days ago, I have created a small `C` code. Example, it allows me to input `1234567890`; and, it will print `0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1` to screen:

```
int n;
printf("n = ");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("\n---\n\n m = ");
while (n)
{
    printf("%d ", n % 10);
    n = n / 10;
}
printf("\n\n---\n\n");
```

---

Now, I tried to create another script, which it allows me to input `1234567890`; and, it will print `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0` to screen.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int n;
    printf("n = ");
    scanf("%d", &n);


    int i1 = 0, n1 = n;
    while (n1 != 0)
    {
        i1 = i1 + 1;
        n1 = n1 / 10;
    }

    printf("\n---\n\nm = ");

    int n2 = n;
    do
    {
        int k = 1, i2 = i1 - 1;
        while (i2 != 0)
        {
            k = k * 10;
            i2 = i2 - 1;
        }

        n2 = n2 / k;
        i1 = i1 - 1;

        printf("%d ", n2);

    }
    while (i1 != 0);

    printf("\n\n---\n\n");
}
```

My code does not print what I want to have: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0`; it always print many zeros: `1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`.

Can you show me what mistakes in my code?

---

How to print `1234567890` to `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0` with `C`?

Comment: What is the value of `n1` when you enter the second (do-while) loop? Since that's the value you're dividing and printing.

Comment: Time for you to learn how to use a debugger! With a debugger you can step through your code line by line, while monitoring variables and their values. Being able to use a debugger is a crucial skill for any programmer.

Comment: Oh no it isn't. `printf("%d ", n1);` pretty clearly prints `n1`. Please use your debugger.

Comment: @YeuSeChia I see that you edited your question to fix that bug, but you still left one spot where you still print n1.

Comment: The correct reaction to a bug in your code is "oops, my fault, thanks", not sneakily edit the question.

Comment: Seems like a lot of work to [just do this](http://ideone.com/977S6Q).

Comment: Re "I am sorry, I do not want to work with string or char*": That will be hard if you want to print something.

Answer (score 1):

By modifying your first small c code, you can obtain the expected display:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    char sNumToText[80]; // to store n in ascii characters

    printf("n = ");
    scanf("%d", &n); // ask for 'n'

    sprintf(sNumToText,"%d",n); // convert integer to text
    printf("\n---\n\n m = ");
    n=0;
    while (sNumToText[n]!='\0')
    {
        printf("%c ", sNumToText[n]); // print one digit and one space
        n ++;
    }
    printf("\n\n---\n\n");

    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursion for the win:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* print n (n >= 1) recursively */
void recurse(int n) {
    if (!n) return;
    recurse(n / 10);
    printf("%d ", n % 10);
}

int main(void) {
    recurse(1234567890);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int n;

    printf("n = ");fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int n1 = n;
    int base = 1;
    while(n1 >= 10){
        n1 /= 10;
        base *= 10;
    }
    printf("\n---\n\nm = ");
    while(base){
        printf("%d ", n1 = n / base);
        n -= n1 * base;
        base /= 10;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `unsigned long long` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to print a string with spaces between characters and avoid the extra trailing space on the last character:

```
void printWithSpaces( const char *input )
{
    // start with zero-length separator
    const char *separator = "";

    while ( *input )
    {
        printf( "%s%c", separator, *input );
        separator = " ";
        input++;
    }
}
```

That will output the string

```
"1234567890"
```

as

```
"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works just fine with me if you enter only single digit integer i.e 0 to 9

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(void){
int c,i=0,k;
int a[100]; //you can enter upto 100 digits;you can change the size if you want
while( (c = getche()) != 13){ //until you hit the enter your input will be taken
    a[i++] = c;
}
for(k = 0;k<i;k++){
    printf("%c ",a[k]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another way to do it using math library:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int n = 0, n1 = 0, n2 = 0;
    int p = 1;

    printf("n = ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    n1 = n;
    while(n1/10 != 0)
    {
        p++;
        n1/=10;
    }

    printf("\n---\n\nm = ");

    n1 = n;
    n2 = n1/pow(10,p);
    while(p>=1)
    {       
        n1 = n1 - n2*pow(10,p);
        n2 = n1/pow(10,p-1);
        printf("%d ", n2);
        p--;
    }

    printf("\n\n---\n\n");
}
```

Or using string conversion:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int n = 0,i,n1,p;
    char *number;

    printf("n = ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    n1 = n;
    while(n1/10 != 0)
    {
        p++;
        n1/=10;
    }

    number = malloc(p+1);
    if(number != NULL)
    {
        printf("\n---\n\nm = ");

        memset(number,0,p+1);
        sprintf(number, "%d", n);
        for (i=0;i<p+1;i++)
        {       
            printf("%c ", number[i]);
        }
        free(number);
    }


    printf("\n\n---\n\n");
}
```

EDIT:

Notice the entered value is `int` the value should be not exceed the maximum value

Use unsigned int is more correct.